# VBA - Runtime Error 1004 - Document Could Not Be Saved

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error, save

The actual error I'm getting is

"Run-time error '1004':

Document not saved."

and then when I hit debug it takes me to the line

```
ActiveWorkbook.Save
```

I've got a giant VBA macro that I'm having some problems with.  The macro is started in a giant workbook with ~75 or so sheets of data.  It starts at the first page, reads the name of the Worksheet to determine which model to run on the data, creates a new workbook, does the calculations and creates the graphs, and then saves the workbook before moving on to the next input sheet.  All of this works fine, except for saving the new workbook.  There are 4 different models I'm running, and 2 of them save correctly.  However, for the other 2 I am faced with this error anytime I try and save them.

```
OutputFolder = "location of output file" 
If Dir(OutputFolder, vbDirectory) = "" Then
MkDir OutputFolder
End If

Workbooks.Open Filename:="location of input file"    '(this is a path to the file)


Workbooks.Open Filename:="location of lookup table" '(another path)
number_of_reports = Workbooks(InputFile).Sheets.Count
Workbooks(InputFile).Activate 


For i = 1 To number_of_reports

ReportID = ActiveSheet.Name 'get 3 part ID
ID_Lookup = Split(ActiveSheet.Name, "-") 'seperate into individual parts


Workbooks("LookupTable").Activate

'use lookup table
Sheets("CompanyLookup").Select
CompanyID = Range("A" & (ID_Lookup(0) + 1))
CompanyName = Range("B" & (ID_Lookup(0) + 1))

Sheets("CategoryLookup").Select
CategoryID = Range("A" & (ID_Lookup(1) + 1))
CategoryName = Range("B" & (ID_Lookup(1) + 1))

Sheets("ModelLookup").Select
ModelID = Range("A" & (ID_Lookup(2) + 1))
ModelName = Range("B" & (ID_Lookup(2) + 1))


Workbooks(InputFile).Activate
y = Range("B1").End(xlToRight).Column
Workbooks(InputFile).Sheets(ReportID).Select

'name of the workbook
SaveID = CategoryName & "_" & ModelName & "_" & FileID

'create company folder if not there already
Output = "location of output" & CompanyName
If Dir(Output, vbDirectory) = "" Then
MkDir Output
End If

'create model folder if not there already
Output = "location of put" & CompanyName & "\" & ModelName
If Dir(Output, vbDirectory) = "" Then
MkDir Output
End If

'where to save workbook
Dim SaveLocation As String
SaveLocation = Output & "\" & SaveID & ".xlsx"

'save workbook
Dim NewBook As Workbook
'create WB for output
Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
With NewBook
    .Title = ReportID
    .Subject = ReportID
    .SaveAs Filename:=SaveLocation
End With



'decide which model to run
If ModelID = 1 Then
Call Regression

ElseIf ModelID = 2 Then
Call VolMix

ElseIf ModelID = 3 Then
Call ProdMix

ElseIf ModelID = 4 Then
Call AvgPrice

End If


Workbooks(SaveID).Activate
Range("A1").Select

deletecheck = Workbooks(SaveID).Sheets.Count

'delete extra sheets
If deletecheck > 3 Then

Call DeleteSheet("Sheet1")
Call DeleteSheet("Sheet2")
Call DeleteSheet("Sheet3")

End If

ActiveWorkbook.Save   'THIS IS WHERE I'M GETTING THE ERROR
ActiveWorkbook.Close

Workbooks(InputFile).Sheets(ReportID).Activate

If i <> number_of_reports Then
ActiveSheet.Next.Select
End If
Next i
```

So models 2 and 4 are the ones giving me problems when they are trying to be saved., the others are not.  I've looked at the code for each of the models and I can't find any difference between the 4 that would be causing this, but obviously something is wrong.  Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: can you edit your post with the actual error you are getting when trying to save?

Comment: sure, I edited the original post

Comment: What is the value of `ActiveWorkbook` at the time the error occurs? Is it `Nothing` when you hover over `ActiveWorkbook`?

Comment: Using a msgbox to print the name of the ActiveWorkbook, it is CategoryName & "_" & ModelName & "_" &FileID &".xlsx"  each time the macro attempts to save any of the workbooks it has created.

Comment: I updated the code by changing the saving/closing method to 'ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True'   this managed to prevent the error from occuring, however the models that were previously giving me the error now don't close and save

Comment: If I stop the macro after it attempts to save the files that are causing the problem and attempt to save them manually, I get this error in excel _Errors were detected while saving "C:\.....  .xlsx".  Microsoft Office Excel may be able to save the file by removing or repairing some features.  To make the repairs in a new file, click Continue.  To cancel saving the file, click Cancel_"

Comment: Then when I click Continue and choose the name/location to save the file, I get another error _Excel enountered errors during save.  However, Excel was able to minially save your file to "C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLA4c.xlsb"_

Comment: Please update the question if you have additional information. Adding comments makes it hard to track the issue.

Comment: I'm getting exactly the same issue, can't find any useful info online.